# Using two letter to reference in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am new with Microsoft excel, I am trying to design a sheet that calculate some equations I downloaded from the Internet, when I put the cursor on the insert function in formula bar appears (BC19+(BF19/3)), usually I am familiar with for example B5 to refer to the cell in the intersection between line 5 and the column B, but this formula (BC19+(BF19/3))?

Can anyone explain to me what it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The letters are for the columns

- A to Z is columns 1-26
- AA to AZ is columns 27-52
- BA to BZ is columns 53-88

BC is column 55

BF is column 58

Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

Or you remove First Letter "B" from the formula.

So it becomes " C19 +  F19/3 " , with which, you are conversant.

Thanks.